# Как импортировать пакеты из той же диреткории в go?

Tags: golang, пакет

У меня есть корневая директория, в которой содержится два пакета. Пакет мэйн и пакет UniqString,
при попытке импортировать UniqString в main ничего не выходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы должны указать полный путь до пакета. вижу у вас есть **go.mod**.  внутри этого файла есть декларация **module**. Значит пакеты должны назваться как `<module>/path/`

например, имеется модуль `module github.com/stackoverflow/questions` в **go.mod** файле, тогда при импорте вы должны указать import `"github.com/stackoverflow/questions/UniqString"`